# SDWebImage Class

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios7, sdwebimage

How can I use this method to perform activity indicator in placeholder ?

```
- (void)createActivityIndicatorWithStyle:(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle) activityStyle {

if ([self activityIndicator] == nil) {
    self.activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:activityStyle];

    self.activityIndicator.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;

    //calculate the correct position
    float width = self.activityIndicator.frame.size.width;
    float height = self.activityIndicator.frame.size.height;
    float x = (self.frame.size.width / 2.0) - width/2;
    float y = (self.frame.size.height / 2.0) - height/2;
    self.activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

    self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
    [self addSubview:self.activityIndicator];
}

[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

}

I appreciate any help

Comment: Where do you put the indicator? is the UIImageView?

Comment: yes i need to do this and put the indicator in the UIImageView placeholder

Comment: It need to modify the open source of the SDWebImage, can you accept ?

Comment: Yes I accept , can You help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way, i use it in this example for updating cells, but it is the same for any use you need.

What i'm doing is setting the UIImageView alpha to 0,Adding a UIActivityIndicatore,and calling a block to get notified when the image has bees loaded.
When its loaded, the UIImageView alpha will be set back to 1, and remove the UIActivityIndicator.

```
 -(void)updateCell {

 self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frameOfCell];
 self.imageView.alpha = 0;
[self addSubview:self.imageView];

//Activity indivator:
self.activity= [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
self.activity.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
self.activity.frame = CGRectMake((frameOfCell.size.width/2)-10, (frameOfCell.size.height/2)-20, 40, 40);
[self.activity startAnimating];
[self addSubview:self.activity];



[self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
NSURL *urlOfImage = [NSURL URLWithString:self.imageName];
self.imageView.alpha = 0;


[self.imageView setImageWithURL:urlOfImage completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
    ///
    self.imageView.alpha = 1;

    //Removing activity indicator:

    [self.activity stopAnimating];
    [self.activity removeFromSuperview];


}];

}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a Category on UIImageView, adding a progress view while images are downloaded using SDWebImage.](https://github.com/kevinrenskers/SDWebImage-ProgressView)

What you should to do is to change `UIProgressView` with `UIActivityIndicatorView`

Try to modify code like this:

```
- (void)removeIndicatorView{
   [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}

- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder options:(SDWebImageOptions)options completed:(SDWebImageCompletedBlock)completedBlock withActivityStyle:(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle) activityStyle {
    [self createActivityIndicatorWithStyle:activityStyle];

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    [self setImageWithURL:url
         placeholderImage:placeholder
                  options:options
                 progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize) {
                     //If you don't care progress, do nothing
                 }
                completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                    [weakSelf removeIndicatorView];
                    if (completedBlock) {
                        completedBlock(image, error, cacheType);
                    }
                }
     ];
}
```